# wordpress contact form 7 issues

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7, custom-wordpress-pages

[eContact us page, contact us form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGM8b.png) **Please check this screenshot (Select your country and Subject field).**

I have installed contact form 7 and adding a field for the select country(Drop down). When I am adding anything next to the drop down menu it's getting down and not working in a perfect row. I have added the screenshot and code below as well.

please let me know if you need more information to move forward.

Looking forward to your help.

```
        <style>
        divTable{
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .divTableRow {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .divTableHeading {
            background-color: #EEE;
            display: table-header-group;
        }
        .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
            border: 0px solid #999999;
            display: table-cell;
            padding: 3px 10px;
        }
        .divTableHeading {
            background-color: #EEE;
            display: table-header-group;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .divTableFoot {
            background-color: #EEE;
            display: table-footer-group;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .divTableBody {
            display: table-row-group;
        }



    #respond .form-submit input[type="submit"], input[type="submit"],
    .wpcf7 input[type="submit"], 
    button[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #05263d;
        color: #fa3f52;
       width: 100%;
       font-weight: 900;
    }




        .wpcf7 .wpcf7-text,
        .wpcf7 .wpcf7-textarea{
          text-indent: 30px;
        }
        .wpcf7 p{ position: relative; }
        .wpcf7 p .fa{
          position: absolute;
          color: #cdcac3;
          z-index: 100;
          font-size: 18px;
          top: 15%;
          left: 3%;
        }
        .wpcf7 p .fa-pencil{ top: 4%; }


        .wpcf7 textarea, .wpcf7 input, .wpcf7 select {
            box-shadow: none;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            padding-left: 25px;

        }

        </style>


        <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">[text* Name: placeholder "Name:"]</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">[email* Email: placeholder "Email:"]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">[tel* Phone: placeholder "Phone:"]</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">[text CompanyName: placeholder "Company Name:"]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">[select* SelectYourCountry: placeholder "Select Your Country:" "Afghanistan " "Albania " "Algeria " "American Samoa " "Andorra " "Angola " "Anguilla " "Antigua & Barbuda " "Argentina " "Armenia " "Aruba " "Australia " "Austria " "Azerbaijan " "Bahamas, The " "Bahrain " "Bangladesh " "Barbados " "Belarus " "Belgium " "Belize " "Benin " "Bermuda " "Bhutan " "Bolivia " "Bosnia & Herzegovina " "Botswana " "Brazil " "British Virgin Is. " "Brunei " "Bulgaria " "Burkina Faso " "Burma " "Burundi " "Cambodia " "Cameroon " "Canada " "Cape Verde " "Cayman Islands " "Central African Rep. " "Chad " "Chile " "China " "Colombia " "Comoros " "Congo, Dem. Rep. " "Congo, Repub. of the " "Cook Islands " "Costa Rica " "Cote d'Ivoire " "Croatia " "Cuba " "Cyprus " "Czech Republic " "Denmark " "Djibouti " "Dominica " "Dominican Republic " "East Timor " "Ecuador " "Egypt " "El Salvador " "Equatorial Guinea " "Eritrea " "Estonia " "Ethiopia " "Faroe Islands " "Fiji " "Finland " "France " "French Guiana " "French Polynesia " "Gabon " "Gambia, The " "Gaza Strip " "Georgia " "Germany " "Ghana " "Gibraltar " "Greece " "Greenland " "Grenada " "Guadeloupe " `enter code here`"Guam " "Guatemala " "Guernsey " "Guinea " "Guinea-Bissau " "Guyana " "Haiti " "Honduras " "Hong Kong " "Hungary " "Iceland " "India " "Indonesia " "Iran " "Iraq " "Ireland " "Isle of Man " "Israel " "Italy " "Jamaica " "Japan " "Jersey " "Jordan " "Kazakhstan " "Kenya " "Kiribati " "Korea, North " "Korea, South " "Kuwait " "Kyrgyzstan " "Laos " "Latvia " "Lebanon " "Lesotho " "Liberia " "Libya " "Liechtenstein " "Lithuania " "Luxembourg " "Macau " "Macedonia " "Madagascar " "Malawi " "Malaysia " "Maldives " "Mali " "Malta " "Marshall Islands " "Martinique " "Mauritania " "Mauritius " "Mayotte " "Mexico " "Micronesia, Fed. St. " "Moldova " "Monaco " "Mongolia " "Montserrat " "Morocco " "Mozambique " "Namibia " "Nauru " "Nepal " "Netherlands " "Netherlands Antilles " "New Caledonia " "New Zealand " "Nicaragua " "Niger " "Nigeria " "N. Mariana Islands " "Norway " "Oman " "Pakistan " "Palau " "Panama " "Papua New Guinea " "Paraguay " "Peru " "Philippines " "Poland " "Portugal " "Puerto Rico " "Qatar " "Reunion " "Romania " "Russia " "Rwanda " "Saint Helena " "Saint Kitts & Nevis " "Saint Lucia " "St Pierre & Miquelon " "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines " "Samoa " "San Marino " "Sao Tome & Principe " "Saudi Arabia " "Senegal " "Serbia " "Seychelles " "Sierra Leone " "Singapore " "Slovakia " "Slovenia " "Solomon Islands " "Somalia " "South Africa " "Spain " "Sri Lanka " "Sudan " "Suriname " "Swaziland " "Sweden " "Switzerland " "Syria " "Taiwan " "Tajikistan " "Tanzania " "Thailand " "Togo " "Tonga " "Trinidad & Tobago " "Tunisia " "Turkey " "Turkmenistan " "Turks & Caicos Is " "Tuvalu " "Uganda " "Ukraine " "United Arab Emirates " "United Kingdom " "United States " "Uruguay " "Uzbekistan " "Vanuatu " "Venezuela " "Vietnam " "Virgin Islands " "Wallis and Futuna " "West Bank " "Western Sahara " "Yemen " "Zambia " "Zimbabwe"]<br></div>
        <div class="divTableCell">[text* Subject: placeholder "Subject:"]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">

        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6">[text* name placeholder "Name"] </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">[text* email placeholder "Email"] </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6">[tel* Phone placeholder "Phone:"] </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">[text CompanyName placeholder "Company Name:"] </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6">[select* YourCountry: placeholder "Select Your Country:" "Afghanistan " "Albania " "Algeria " "American Samoa " "Andorra " "Angola " "Anguilla " "Antigua & Barbuda " "Argentina " "Armenia " "Aruba " "Australia " "Austria " "Azerbaijan " "Bahamas, The " "Bahrain " "Bangladesh " "Barbados " "Belarus " "Belgium " "Belize " "Benin " "Bermuda " "Bhutan " "Bolivia " "Bosnia & Herzegovina " "Botswana " "Brazil " "British Virgin Is. " "Brunei " "Bulgaria " "Burkina Faso " "Burma " "Burundi " "Cambodia " "Cameroon " "Canada " "Cape Verde " "Cayman Islands " "Central African Rep. " "Chad " "Chile " "China " "Colombia " "Comoros " "Congo, Dem. Rep. " "Congo, Repub. of the " "Cook Islands " "Costa Rica " "Cote d'Ivoire " "Croatia " "Cuba " "Cyprus " "Czech Republic " "Denmark " "Djibouti " "Dominica " "Dominican Republic " "East Timor " "Ecuador " "Egypt " "El Salvador " "Equatorial Guinea " "Eritrea " "Estonia " "Ethiopia " "Faroe Islands " "Fiji " "Finland " "France " "French Guiana " "French Polynesia " "Gabon " "Gambia, The " "Gaza Strip " "Georgia " "Germany " "Ghana " "Gibraltar " "Greece " "Greenland " "Grenada " "Guadeloupe " `enter code here`"Guam " "Guatemala " "Guernsey " "Guinea " "Guinea-Bissau " "Guyana " "Haiti " "Honduras " "Hong Kong " "Hungary " "Iceland " "India " "Indonesia " "Iran " "Iraq " "Ireland " "Isle of Man " "Israel " "Italy " "Jamaica " "Japan " "Jersey " "Jordan " "Kazakhstan " "Kenya " "Kiribati " "Korea, North " "Korea, South " "Kuwait " "Kyrgyzstan " "Laos " "Latvia " "Lebanon " "Lesotho " "Liberia " "Libya " "Liechtenstein " "Lithuania " "Luxembourg " "Macau " "Macedonia " "Madagascar " "Malawi " "Malaysia " "Maldives " "Mali " "Malta " "Marshall Islands " "Martinique " "Mauritania " "Mauritius " "Mayotte " "Mexico " "Micronesia, Fed. St. " "Moldova " "Monaco " "Mongolia " "Montserrat " "Morocco " "Mozambique " "Namibia " "Nauru " "Nepal " "Netherlands " "Netherlands Antilles " "New Caledonia " "New Zealand " "Nicaragua " "Niger " "Nigeria " "N. Mariana Islands " "Norway " "Oman " "Pakistan " "Palau " "Panama " "Papua New Guinea " "Paraguay " "Peru " "Philippines " "Poland " "Portugal " "Puerto Rico " "Qatar " "Reunion " "Romania " "Russia " "Rwanda " "Saint Helena " "Saint Kitts & Nevis " "Saint Lucia " "St Pierre & Miquelon " "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines " "Samoa " "San Marino " "Sao Tome & Principe " "Saudi Arabia " "Senegal " "Serbia " "Seychelles " "Sierra Leone " "Singapore " "Slovakia " "Slovenia " "Solomon Islands " "Somalia " "South Africa " "Spain " "Sri Lanka " "Sudan " "Suriname " "Swaziland " "Sweden " "Switzerland " "Syria " "Taiwan " "Tajikistan " "Tanzania " "Thailand " "Togo " "Tonga " "Trinidad & Tobago " "Tunisia " "Turkey " "Turkmenistan " "Turks & Caicos Is " "Tuvalu " "Uganda " "Ukraine " "United Arab Emirates " "United Kingdom " "United States " "Uruguay " "Uzbekistan " "Vanuatu " "Venezuela " "Vietnam " "Virgin Islands " "Wallis and Futuna " "West Bank " "Western Sahara " "Yemen " "Zambia " "Zimbabwe"] </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">[text* Subject placeholder "Subject:"] </div>
</div>
```

try to use above code instead of yours and tell me what happen.

Comment: This is working amazingly. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot